# detect white areas with sharp boundary

Tags: algorithm, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

In the grayscale image shown below, how can I accurately detect the white region having sharp boundary (marked with red color)?

In this particular image, a simple thresholding might work, however, I have several images in which there are similar areas around corner of images which I want to ignore.

Also, there might be more than one regions of interest, both having different intensities. One can be as bright as it is in the example image, other can be of medium intensity.

However, the only difference between the interested and non-interested areas is as follows:

1. The interest areas have sharp well defined boundaries.
2. Non-interested areas don't have sharp boundaries. They tend to gradually merge with neighbourhood areas.

[image: no-flash/flash ratio image]

Image without mark for testing: 
[image: image for test]

Comment: Do the areas also have to be of a minimum size or  what does the white stripe distinguish from the edges of the people and the other stuff on the picture?

Comment: May I ask what you want to achieve and what your setup is?

Comment: @Gilfoy, there is no minimum size as such. The white strip marked in the picture is a sharp shadow in flash image.

Comment: @Piglet: Basically I am trying to detect sharp shadows at silhouettes in flash images. The image which you are seeing is a ratio image of no-flash and flash intensity. It highlights shadow areas.

Comment: Can  you  add  your  input image without any marks?

Comment: @BalajiR: Added. Please check now.

Comment: So you actually have two images, one with flash shadow and one without? Can you please post them?

Comment: @Gilfoy: I have added those images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say sharp boundaries, you have to think gradient. The sharper the boundaries, the bigger the gradient. Therefore apply a gradient and you will see that it will be stronger around the shapes you want to segment.

But in your case, you can also observe that the area you want to segment is also the brightest. So I would also try a noise reduction (median filter) plus a convolution filter (simple average) in order to homogenize the different zones, then thresholding by keeping only the brightest/right peak.

Comment: It is not necessary that the areas which I want to segment will be brightest. I am a novice in image processing, can you please add some more detail about: "try a noise reduction plus a convolution filter in order to homogenize the different zones, then thresholding by keeping only the brightest/right peak"? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
im = imread('o2XfN.jpg');
figure
imshow(im)
smooth = imgaussfilt(im,.8); %"blur" the image to take out noisey pixels
big = double(smooth);   % some functions don't work with UINT8, I didn't check for these
maxiRow = quantile(big,.99);   % .99 qualtile... think quartile from stats
maxiCol = quantile(maxiRow,.98);  % again for the column
pixels = find(big>=maxiCol);  % which pixels have the highest values

logicMat = false(size(big));  %initalize a logic matrix of zeros
logicMat(pixels) = 1;  %set the pixels that passed to logic pass
figure
imshow(logicMat)
```

It is not extremely clear what you want to do with the regions that you are finding. Also, a few more sample images would be helpful to debug a code. What I posted above may work for that one image, but it is unlikely that it will work for every image that you are processing.